# Ruby on Rails getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I'm using similar code to Railscast 213 to display a calendar with records.

The do line is causing a "getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 0):

```
<%= calendar @date do |date| %>
    <%= date.day %>
    <% if @wolabors_by_date[date] %>
      <ul>
        <% @wolabors_by_date[date].each do |wolabor| %>
          <li><%= link_to wolabor.name, wolabor %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>   
<% end %>
```

The calendar_helper.rb starts out with:

```
module CalendarHelper
    def calendar(date = Date.today, &block)
        Calendar.new(self, date, block).table   
    end
```

wolabors_controller.rb has

```
class WolaborsController <     ApplicationController
def index
  @wolabors = Wolabor.all
  @wolabors_by_date = @wolabors.group_by(&:date)
  @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
end`
```

Comment: what line is giving you the error?

Comment: <%= calendar @date do |date| %>

Comment: ok then I think the correct method is calendar_for

Comment: Could you post your @date definition in the controller index action ? I've found in the discussion about this Railscast , that the statement :first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY) gives the same arguments error . These methods are Rails 3.2 specific and if you are on lower version , you should upgrade .

Comment: I just put the @date def in the original question

Comment: I'm using 3.1.3 - I'll upgrade - thanks!!!

Comment: I hope everything is Ok now . If you have solved the problem , just tell us .

Comment: I have never upgraded Rails app before.  I'm upgrading this app from 3.1.3 to 3.2.8 -- and I'm running into issues with gems that are locking me at certain levels.  But, that's a different issue. Thanks for the help!  Qumara - if you enter your answer about the versions, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that first line is supposed to be

```
<% calendar_for @date do |date| %>
```

That railscast has been revised and it does not use that table_builder plugin in the new version.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised

Comment: That gives me: undefined method `calendar_for' for #<#<Class:0x007f84b00e02e0>:0x007f84b0019398>

Comment: you are missing the plugin

Comment: script/plugin install git://github.com/p8/table_builder.git

Comment: 213 revised doesn't use the calendar_for

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what table_builder has to do with it.

Comment: I believe it provides that calendar_for method

Comment: I'm think 'script/plugin install' command is so Rails 2 :) I believe mr. Dave Burton is on Rails 3.2 ...

Comment: ahh sorry, I understand now. I thought the question was more about the railscast. I guess there must be something wrong with that helper method. Regardless I would checkout the revised episode which provides a helper method for building the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I've found in the discussion about this Railscast , that the statement :

```
first = date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week(START_DAY)
```

gives the same arguments error . It seems methods

```
beginning_of_month
```

and

```
beginning_of_week
```

are Rails 3.2 specific and if you are on lower version , you should upgrade.